# In JSSOR, how do you add additional slides to the full width slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I'm working in the JSSOR full-width slider JQuery demo and I cannot figure out how to add additional slides. Currently, it holds 3 slides and I'd like to add 2 more. I have attempted to add additional slide divs and look for the option in the sript options in the top and the jssor.slider.js file. But I don't know where the total number of slides is defined for a particular example. I've seen the vars that define how a slider keeps track of rows, cols, and its index, but I've never seen an explicit declaration.

Edited to include html code. Sorry about that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Full Width Slider - Jssor Slider, Slideshow</title>
</head>
<body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Verdana;background-color:#fff;">
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var _CaptionTransitions = [];
            _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 4, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTT|2"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 3, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $FlyDirection: 10, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $ScaleHorizontal: 0.6, $ScaleVertical: 0.6, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
            _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 15, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };
            _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };

            var options = {
                $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, default value is 0
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
                $SlideDuration: 1200,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                if (bodyWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles (except 'top', 'left', 'width' and 'height') to css file or css block. -->
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
        top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px;
            height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">

            <!-- Slide #1 -->
            <div>
                <!-- Background holder -->
                <img u="image" src="../img/1920/background.png" />

                <!-- Right half of container -->
                <div u="caption" style="position: absolute; width: 445px; height: 300px; top: 0px; left: 800px;">

                    <img src="../img/1920/1.png" style="height:800px; width:auto"/>


                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 30px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 50px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">Sample Product
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 300px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 36px; font-size: 30px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                    </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Slide #2 -->
            <div>
                <!-- Background holder -->
                <img u="image" src="../img/1920/yellow.png" />

                <!-- Right half of container -->
                <div u="caption" style="position: absolute; width: 445px; height: 300px; top: 0px; left: 800px;">

                    <img src="../img/1920/2.png" style="height:600px; width:auto"/>


                </div>

                <!-- Left half of container -->
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 30px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 50px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">Sample Product
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 300px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 36px; font-size: 30px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Slide #3 -->
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/1920/orange.png" />

                <!-- Right half of container -->
                <div u="caption" style="position: absolute; width: 445px; height: 300px; top: 0px; left: 800px;">

                    <img src="../img/1920/3.png" style="height:800px; width:auto"/>


                </div>

                <!-- Left half of container -->
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 30px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 50px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">Sample Product
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 300px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 36px; font-size: 30px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                </div>


            <!-- What should be Slide #4, but isn't working -->
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/1920/orange.png" />

                <!-- Right half of container -->
                <div u="caption" style="position: absolute; width: 445px; height: 300px; top: 0px; left: 800px;">

                    <img src="../img/1920/3.png" style="height:800px; width:auto"/>


                </div>

                <!-- Left half of container -->
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 30px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 50px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">Sample Product
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 300px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                    text-align: left; line-height: 36px; font-size: 30px;
                        color: #FFFFFF;">
                        Lorem Ipsum
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 21 css */
            /*
            .jssorb21 div           (normal)
            .jssorb21 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb21 .av           (active)
            .jssorb21 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb21 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb21 div, .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av
            {
                background: url(../img/b21.png) no-repeat;
                overflow:hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .jssorb21 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
            .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
            .jssorb21 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
            .jssorb21 .dn, .jssorb21 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb21" style="position: absolute; bottom: 26px; left: 6px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 19px; HEIGHT: 19px; text-align:center; line-height:19px; color:White; font-size:12px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 21 css */
            /*
            .jssora21l              (normal)
            .jssora21r              (normal)
            .jssora21l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora21r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora21ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora21rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora21l, .jssora21r, .jssora21ldn, .jssora21rdn
            {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(../img/a21.png) center center no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .jssora21l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
            .jssora21r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
            .jssora21l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
            .jssora21r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
            .jssora21ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
            .jssora21rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora21l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora21r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Including a block of html/code or a [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) showing an example of what you've tried that didn't work will often help others figure out what's going on. For example: did you include the `u="image"` attribute on the `<img>` tags as @jason-belmonti mentions? We don't know, because you haven't posted any code.

Comment: Added code. And I'll reply to jason-belmonti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks an enclosing '' is missing for slide #3.

I guess it would be OK to replace,

```
<!-- What should be Slide #4, but isn't working -->
```

with

```
</div>
<!-- What should be Slide #4, but isn't working -->
```

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like you just add more div tags](http://www.jssor.com/development/):

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="image1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image2.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image3.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="image4.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="imageX.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont think the number of slides is going to be explicitly declared anywhere in the JS file, that would make it kind of not-awesome.  Instead, I'm sure its just looking for elements underneath `<div u="slides"></div>`.  Notice how all the images are contained in divs and have a `u="image"` attribute.

Comment: I agree that it would be not-awesome. But I have tried adding additional divs. I've edited my original post to show all of the code, it defaults with three slides but when I copy the third slide to test a 4th possible slide, it simply rotates through the original three slides and doesn't adjust the bullet navigator.